# iPhone - One View with Many UITableView's

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am working on an iPhone view that has some header text along with a `UISegmentedControl` at the top and a `UITableView` beneath it.  When a different segment is selected in the `UISegmentedControl`, I need a different set of records to be displayed in the `UITableView`.

What is the best way to implement this?  Should I have one `UITableView` for the view controller and just re-populate it when a different segment is selected?  If so, can this be done with a `NSFetchedResultsController` / core data?

Thanks!
-Johann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a different Table View Controller class for each one needed view.  This will keep the logic of each view self-contained.  Then instantiate, add and remove the subviews as needed when the user selects a different option.  You would also be able to animate transitions from one to the next in some meaningful way.

If you decide later that one set of information would be better served using a different kind of view, you don't have to untangle everything.